# How to paste line but preserve the cursor position?

Tags: paste

I want to achieve following. Imagine I have a line of code, say:

```
std::cout << "STEP #0" << "\r\n";
```

Now I want to paste it somewhere else, but I want to stay cursor in line exactly in the same position after pasting as it was in the original line.

I want to be able to do this so that I'll be able to modifier some specific substring in the line pasted quicker, without re-navigating to where I was.

Is it doable at all?

Comment: Everything is possible yet only some things are worth effort. I mean you can trap `:h TextYankPost` and manually track (register name, cursor position) pair while yanking the text. Then also map p/P/gp/gP and whatsoever to restore cursor column too. But does it really worth?

Comment: I don't understand your question. When you're pasting text, wouldn't your cursor be on the line where you're pasting? Or are you talking about doing something like `:50p`? Then I'd harmonize with Matt and suggest using `Ctrl-O` to jump back to previous position (`:h jumplist`).